# How to convert unix time to qt time type?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, convert, qgis-custom-function, timestamp

How can I convert unix timestamp to qt time type using qgis field calculator? I would like to avoid importing my table into excel and convert the timestamp to qt time type.

Answer (score 4):

This is fairly easy to do using the Field calculator and a simple custom function. The result is a string, which you can coerce to a proper time/date class later (e.g. for some proper date/time calculations), or extend the script to do that for you.

Open `Field calculator` and click the `Function editor` tab. You can create a new `New file` or extend an existing one with the following few lines of (Python) code:

```
"""
Define new functions using @qgsfunction. feature and parent must always be the
last args. Use args=-1 to pass a list of values as arguments
"""

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import time

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def fromSecToDate(value1, feature, parent):
    outtime = time.gmtime(value1)
    outtime = time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y", outtime)
    return outtime
```

It should look like this in 2.18.3.

[image]

Once you're done, do not forget to hit the `Load` button. Now switch to `Expression` tab and find `fromSecToDate` function under the `Custom` group (as defined in the script, feel free to modify). Don't forget to properly name your variables and set the Output field type to `Text (string)`.

[image]

To be able to coerce to a `date` format, you'll need to modify the above script by changing the order of units: year-month-day

```
time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y", outtime)
```

and then in the `Expression tab` creating a new Date type field using

```
to_date(fromSecToDate("yourvariable"))
```

Answer (score 3):

if not availble you can always create your own convertion function:

http://nathanw.net/2012/11/10/user-defined-expression-functions-for-qgis/

and should be good to share it in some place or to propose to insert in the expression library

Comment: @euler For the actual conversion, consider leveraging [one of Qt's QTime.fromString(...) static functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtime.html#fromString).

Answer (score 3):

From QGIS 3.12 it's possible to use in the Field Calculator build-in method `datetime_from_epoch()` that converts Unix Timestamp to QGIS Date & Time value.

https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog312/index.html#feature-add-datetime-from-epoch-msec-from-epoch-expression-function

Comment: Pair it with `to_date()` to show it as a friendly, human readable date string.