# Converting Unix epoch time to GMT time using QGIS Field Calculator

Tags: qgis, time, date

I am trying to convert the 'time' and 'updated' column from epoch to date/time GMT but I am struggling to do so. I know I have to use the field calculator tab but I am a basic at using scripting.

I am using QGIS.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Questions here are expected to show some effort toward resolution. Coding questions are expected to contain code. In this case, the image should be augmented with an ASCII table with 4-5 rows of {ID, time, updated} values. Unix epoch *is* GMT time, in seconds since midnight on 01-Jan-1970, so all you need to do is research the Python datetime.datetime class.

Comment: Here is your answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/373269/107424

Answer (score 1):

In the QGIS python console, you should be able to run something like:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp({your epoch time}).strftime('%c')
```

Note that strftime can be formatted in many ways, but the time zone will be UTC.
For instance, you could instead use the following: strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
(See strftime for the possible formatting values)

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` assigns the local time zone to the object.  add the optional `tz=datetime.timezone.utc` parameter.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that epoch time is already in UTC?? So you are saying that the fromtimestamp puts it into the local time zone?  How does it know what that is??

Comment: It applies the platform timezone.  I used "0" and it reported 31-Dec-1969 @ 1900 for my EDT host. If I add tz=datetime.timezone.utc, then it reports 01-Jan-1970 @ 0000